# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression in function call python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

```
def orders(**sandwich):
    sand={}
    for category,toppings in sandwich.items():
        sand[category]=toppings
        return sand 

    orders('cheese'='extra','toppings'='mushroom')
    print(orders)
```

This is the code which i wrote for a mini project but i get this error
**SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression**
Please rectify it and i am a newbie so please explain deely
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Keyword args must be identifiers, not strings:

```
orders(cheese='extra', toppings='mushroom')
```

Also, note that you are returning `sand` on the first iteration of the loop.

And also, `sandwich` is already a dict. Actually your function could be replaced with:

```
d = dict(cheese='extra', toppings='mushroom')
print(d)
```